# Округление числа до целых

Tags: powershell

Доброго времени суток!
Есть переменная $a = 37,5 (с запятой) в **powershell**. Как её округлить до целых? Пробовал так:

```
[math]::Round($a, 0)
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
Не удается найти перегрузку для "Round" и количества аргументов: "2".
строка:1 знак:1
+ [math]::Round($a, 0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Когда ввожу само значение, вместо переменной

```
[math]::Round(37,5, 0)
```

то всё работает:

```
37
```

Comment: `[math]::Round(37,5, 0)` - Тут у вас 3 параметра.

Comment: Именно так, используется 3 параметра, а не 2 от автора, поэтому ему кажется, что все работает как он ожидает.  static double Round(double value, int digits, System.MidpointRounding mode)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что текущая конфигурация ожидает . (точку) в качестве разделителя дробной части, и объявляя переменную через **$a = 37,5** создается массив с двумя числами, 37 и 5, что и вызывает данную ошибку.

`(Get-Culture).NumberFormat` покажет текущие настройки разделителей дробных частей.

Проблема в данном случае не в том, что в переменной содержится число с запятой в качестве разделителя. Переменная изначально инициализирована как массив:

```
$a =  37,5
PS C:\> $a.GetType().BaseType.Name
Array
PS C:\> $a.Count
2
```

Также, символ разделителя целой и дробной части определяется текущими региональными настройками системы (сессии). Но задавать ты значение должен через точку, даже, если у тебя стоит запятая. Иначе будет восприниматся как массив.

Comment: вот, как округлить значение с запятой?

Comment: @mocart поменять региональные настройки на хосте или привести значение переменной в $a =  '37,5'.Replace(',','.')

Comment: Значение должно оставаться числом, а не строкой. и нужно сделать, как-нибудь без замены региональных настроек

Comment: Проблема не в значении с запятой. Создавая переменную с текущими региональными настройками в переменной всегда будет содержатся два числа, 37 и 5. проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell выводит числа с разделителем по регионам, у нас у всех это очевидно запятая. Но вводить числа самому нужно всегда по американски с точкой. Потому что запятая это "оператор создания массива".
При вводе `3.14` это число,
`"3.14"` или `"3,14"` это строки.
Округлить до целого проще так: `[int]3.14`

До любого знака: `[math]::Round(3.1416, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Сперва я пробовал отформатировать число - но забыл, что в этом случае (когда отбрасываются все цифры после запятой) округление всегда будет идти только в меньшую сторону.

Мне кажется, удалось найти самое короткое и работающее решение. Увы, если попадается ноль после запятой, оно не работает. Однако оставлю его здесь пока что.

Если строка распознается как числовое значение, то она будет считаться числом (за некоторыми исключениями, которые в данном случае никак нам не мешают).

```
$a = 37,5  
$ofs = '.'  
$a = [string]$a 
$a = [math]::Round($a)  
$a
```

P.S. Не работает для чисел (хотя на самом деле это получается не число, а массив) вида 3,0007 - преобразует в 3.7 и округляет до 4.

Comment: `$a = 37,00005`

Comment: Скриншот можно в студию?
мой тут: https://yadi.sk/i/mhFk4yX43FXJ8p

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTluh.png

Comment: И правда, 37,00005 сокращается до 37,5.... Надо по-другому попробовать

Comment: '37,0005'.Replace(',','.') - работает, а вот как преобразовать $a в строку - пока не пойму, нолики пропадают в  $a = [string]$a  :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно использовать метд с 1м параметром:.

   PS C:> $a = 22/7

   PS C:> $a

   3.14285714285714

   PS C:> [math]::Round($a)

   3
2. Задавать ты значение должен через точку, даже, если у тебя стоит запятая в региональных настройках. Иначе будет восприниматся как массив.

> $a = 37,5

Это сделано что бы ты мог задавать независимо от региональных настройек с одинаковым синтаксисом значения как в аррей (14.4, 14.5, 1.4) так и напрямую (13.4) потому как если бы это влияло --- это вызвало бы проблемы с (14,4, 14,5, 1,4)

Comment: $a = 37,5 - из-за региональных настроек (а может еще из-за чего) стоит запятая, однако при этом такая переменная распознается как массив. Попробуйте в вашем ответе заменить 3.14285714285714 на 3,14285714285714 - и ничего не выйдет :(

Comment: Но задавать ты значение должен через точку, даже, если у тебя стоит запятая в региональных настройках. Иначе будет восприниматся как массив.